# How to get records of last week?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am able to get records of current week.

But I want to get the records of last week:

My code till now:

```
select * from T1
where WorkDate >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))   
AND WorkDate <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? What is the result of your websearch, and what needs to be clarified? What 'week' means? (7 days back from now or from Monday to Sunday?) Please edit your question and provide some additional information. Also please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153687/always-return-data-from-last-weeks-monday-thru-sunday

Answer (score 1):

i think this work for you [change table to yours]

```
SELECT M.[mId],M.[mName],M.mInsertDate
    FROM dbo.TblMusic M 
    WHERE DATEPART(ww,M.[mInsertDate])=DATEPART(ww,GETDATE()-7)
    ORDER BY M.mInsertDate DESC
```

Comment: The code assumes that years are not important. DATEPART(ww,GETDATE()-7) is equal to DATEPART(ww,GETDATE()-365-7) because each year has same week numbers. And, on top of that, the question is a duplicate of 7153687.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table
(
    id int primary key,
    created_date date,
    data varchar(10)
  )

insert into @t values (1,'2012-01-01','testing');

SELECT Created_Date
FROM @t
WHERE Created_Date >= DATEADD(day,-11117, GETDATE())
```

or

```
SELECT Created_Date
FROM Table_Name
WHERE Created_Date >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```